# How to remove borders that overlap each other in a table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created the table, but where 2 cells meet, the border is darker and thicker. How can I solve this issue? Here's my CSS code.

```
.custom-table-2 {
  border-collapse: separate;
  /*border-collapse: collapse;*/
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.custom-table-2 td {
  border: 1px solid #00953B;
}

.custom-table-2 tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border: 0px;
}

.custom-table-2 tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
}

.custom-table-2 tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
}

.custom-table-2 tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
}
.custom-table-2 td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #7CCB99;
}
```

[Image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs4kV.png)

If I use 'border-collapse: collapse;', it won't be thicker, but then the border radii won't show. Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Can you show your html too?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you have, and also a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please always present a proper [mre], when asking this kind of question here.

Comment: If you can't use `border-collapse: collapse`, then your only other option is to see to it that one of the two meeting cells will _not_ have a border, on that side where they meet.

Comment: We don't need an image of the table, we need the code to re-create the table

Answer (score 0):

Set individual borders for `<td>`, not shorthand:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  border-left: 1px solid #00953B;
  border-top: 1px solid #00953B;
  padding: 20px;
}

table td:last-child {
  border-right: solid 1px #00953B;
}

table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #00953B;
}

table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border: 0px;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
}

table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
}

table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
}

table td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #7CCB99;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```